# Is there a way to use block comments after a GO in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an auto-generated SQL script with this basic structure:

```
/*
*/
PRINT 'Stuff'
GO
/*
*/
PRINT 'Other stuff'
```

The problem is that SQL Server doesn't seem to like block comments when they are placed after a `GO`.  There is a bug for this on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/361251/fatal-script-error-incorrect-syntax-was-encountered-while-parsing-go-incorrectly-parses-comment) (set to won't-fix, sigh) and a guy named Devi posted [some workarounds](http://sqlserverlearner.com/tag/error-with-multiline-comment-after-go-statement), but they don't really work for me because my script is auto-generated.

I can insert something *after* the `GO` and *before* the second block comment.  I've tried various things in there, however, without changing the failing outcome which, fwiw, is this helpful text:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ''.

Is there anything I can stick in between the `GO` and the comment to avoid this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue seems to be of a different nature, and two things point to that.

1. The linked Connect page is about `/* ... */` comment after `GO` *on the same line* with it, but in your case the comment starts *on the line that follows* `GO`.
2. The issue you are alluding to produces this error message:

   ```
   A fatal scripting error occurred.
   Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.
   ```

   But yours is different:

   ```
   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
   Incorrect syntax near ''.
   ```

I'm going to guess here (but not unreasonably, I hope) that your script generator uses Mac style line breaks (`0x0D`) instead of Windows style ones (`0x0D0A`). I was able to almost reproduce the issue using Mac line breaks, but in my case the error was just a little bit different from yours:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

Still it seems close enough for me to suggest you check what kind of line breaks your script generator uses.

Comment: Ah!  A hex view showed I had a UTF-8 BOM (0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) just prior to the comment.  Thank you very much for the investigation!

Comment: @ladenedge: Didn't quite expect that! But with code generation, I guess, even more unexpected things should be possible. :) Thanks for the feedback.